# How to set up bluestacks emulator to receive firebase cloud messaging push notifications of my android app ?

Tags: android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, bluestacks

How to set up bluestacks emulator to receive firebase cloud messaging push notifications of my android app  ? 
The firebase console is keeping the status of message to "*completed*" but my bluestacks emulator which has the GMail app installed and logged in, is not receivng the push notifiations.

Comment: You're using GMail...? Are you sure that the registration token registered for that app is the one from the bluestacks emulator?

Comment: yes, Registration token is getting generated for BlueStacks emulator. But when I send message from Firebase, it doesn't show up in Bluestacks emulator. I have updated both GMail and PlayStore.